# Combine data from several queries

Tags: jasper-reports

We are looking into a more powerful way of collecting and processing data to be processed in our reports. For one advanced report on a big database, we need to run two indepedent SQL queries (on the same data source) and combine them afterwards.

Query1 returns:

```
user id#1 ... 3 columns
user id#2 ... 3 columns
user id#4 ... 3 columns
```

Query 2 returns:

```
user id#1 ... 5 columns
user id#3 ..  5 columns
user id#4 ... 5 columns
```

What we want to show:

```
user id#1 ... 3 columns + 5 columns
user id#2 ... 3 columns
user id#3 ... 5 columns
user id#4 ... 3 columns + 5 columns
```

Although it's counter-intuitive, we found that combining the results from both queries in SQL leads to considerably worse runtime of the SQL query.

We have looked at subdatasets, but from my understanding it's not possible to mix the data from two subdatasets (or the main data+one subdataset) in a single table.

We have looked at subreports, but from my understanding a subreport will call the query once for each row in the report, if I put the subreport in the Details area as we intend to. But for performance reasons we want to run the two queries that we prepared, and each only once.

We think the most reasonnable approach is for us to write such advanced reports in Java, and it's possible, however the JavaBean data source cannot access the report parameters. Our database is huge and therefore we can't just make queries without where and filter afterwards, the Java code needs access to the report parameters.

We are currently looking into implementing JRQueryExecutor [as recommended there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4819766/can-jasper-reports-use-filterable-custom-data-sources) and [there (last comment)](http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/505618/problem-parameters-custom-datasource), or even taking advantage of scriptlets.

But it sounds really quite advanced and we are wondering are we thinking the wrong way or heading in the wrong direction? And if JRQueryExecutor is the correct way any example or documentation would be welcome.

We are also considering trying to refactor our SQL to achieve the result with only one query, but we do feel that the reporting system ought to allow us to manipulate the data also in Java.

Comment: May be you need just use SQL Join?

Comment: I mentioned "Although it's counter-intuitive, we found that combining the results from both queries in SQL leads to considerably worse runtime of the SQL query."

Comment: Its takes long time? Are you sure that the post-processing will be faster in jasper?

Comment: It is faster in raw java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end we made it with a scriptlet. In `afterReportInit`, inheriting `JRDefaultScriptlet` you get the parameters and the data source from `parametersMap`, and you can then fill in the data source from Java.